# Convergence of nested sin and cos

Tags: trigonometry, convergence-divergence

Let's define the following: $A_1 = x, A_j = \cos(\sin A_{j - 1})$.

I notice that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $A_\infty \approx 0.768169157$

Is there an exact value for $A_\infty$?

Comment: I remember noticing that as a high-schooler.  I don't think there's any interesting closed-form expression for it, but maybe someone will chime in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for all $A_1\in \mathbb{R}$ the recurrence $(A_n)_n$ converges  to $A_{\infty}$ which is the [unique fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) of the [contraction mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) $f(x)=\cos(\sin(x))$. This means that $A_{\infty}$ is the only solution of the equation
$$x = \cos(\sin (x)).$$
I'm afraid that the real number $A_{\infty}\approx 0.768169156736795977$ has not a "closed form".

P.S. The function $f$ is a contraction over $\mathbb{R}$ because for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$|f'(x)|=|-\sin(\sin(x))\cos(x)|\leq \sin(1)<1.$$